# How can i open 4 Different url with 4 button in android app?

Tags: android

How can I open 4 Different URL with 4 buttons in android app?
 For example, button_1 open facebook.com, button_2 open google.com, button_3 open wwe.com and button_4 open cnn.com. I want to make web view in class "ShowWeb" not in "MainActivity".

Comment: Create ShowWeb activity with a webview in its xml file and on clicking each button pass the url of the website you want to load using intent and dynamically load the webview with that url

Comment: Possible code example explains this plez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample program . You have to add the rest of the code for each button click.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1,button2,button3,button4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent next = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                next.putExtra("url","www.facebook.com");
                startActivity(next);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.invis.ktpms.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**NextActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

        String Url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

        WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.loadUrl(Url);
    }
}
```

**activity_next.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.invis.ktpms.NextActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```